# How to create a loop to add info in the AD with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am a kind of a newbie in Powershell yet, can someone please tell me how i can create a loop (purpose is to add the info to all the people (usernames) in the .CSV list)

This is what i got now, tryed many things but still no good..

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$username = Import-Csv c:\user.csv

Set-ADuser -Identity $Username -Company "Company name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a foreach loop.

**Example:**

```
foreach($user in $username)
{
  //some action for example
  Set-ADuser -Identity $user -Company "A Company"
}
```

**Reference:**

http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/logic-using-loops/

I'd also recommend adding some sort of logging (using either add-content or write-host) to track the progress of the script, if the file has a lot of entries.

regards
Arcass